# @FunctionalInterface that also implements andThen?

Tags: java, function, generics, functional-interface

I'm trying to create a functional interface that can throw an custom exception, what I've come up with is.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingFunction<T, R> {
  R apply(T t) throws MyException;
}
```

This works great for using the apply function but the problem is I'd also like to use the andThen capabilities of Java's functions. When I try to do something like.

```
ThrowingFunction<Integer, Integer> times2WithException = (num) -> {
    if(num == null) {
       throw new MyException("Cannot multiply null by 2");
    }
    return num * 2;
};
times2WithException.andThen(times2WithException).apply(4);
```

I get the error

```
Cannot find symbol: method andThen(ThrowingFunction<Integer, Integer>)
```

Is there something I should use instead of FunctionalInterface? Or is there another function I need to implement to get it to work with andThen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional interfaces are only allowed to specify one unimplemented function. But you can specify `default` functions that already have an implementation like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingFunction<T, R> {
  R apply(T t) throws MyException;

  default <U> ThrowingFunction<T, U> andThen(ThrowingFunction<R, U> follow) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(follow); // Fail fast
    return t -> follow.apply(this.apply(t));
  }
}
```

Comment: 3 seconds later than Jacob with virtually the same implementation

Answer (score 2):

Where are you expecting the `andThen` method to come from?  You haven't defined it anywhere!

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ThrowingFunction<T, R> {
    R apply(T t) throws MyException;

    default <V> ThrowingFunction<T, V> andThen(ThrowingFunction<R, V> after) {
        return (T t) -> after.apply(apply(t));
    }
}
```

Here, you can take advantage of `default` methods in interfaces to create an `andThen` function.